# jQuery - click function not working after remove() is used

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sample of HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="ThumbnailHolder">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <img src="http://images.sportsdirect.com/images/products/16503236_pit.jpg" class="Thumbnails" bigimagelink="http://images.sportsdirect.com/images/products/16503236_l.jpg">
        <img src="http://images.sportsdirect.com/images/products/16503236_piat_a1.jpg" class="Thumbnails" bigimagelink="http://images.sportsdirect.com/images/products/16503236_l_a1.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.Thumbnails').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
                  var BigImageLink = $( this ).attr( "bigimagelink" );
                  $('#ImgBigLink').attr('href', BigImageLink);
                  $('#productImgDefault').attr('src', BigImageLink);
        });

    });     
});
```

This function is working great. When i click an element with class `Thumbnails` everything goes how i need. The Problem comes when i execute the following part of code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'CheckColorPrice.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        url: '<?php echo $url;?>',
        ColorId: ColorNumber,
        ProductUrl: '<?PHP echo $ProductUrlWithoutCode;?>'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
            $( ".Thumbnails" ).remove();
            $.each(data.thumbnails, function(index, thumbnails) {                             
            $('#ThumbnailHolder div').append('<img src="http://images.sportsdirect.com/images/products/' + thumbnails + '" class="Thumbnails" bigimagelink="http://images.sportsdirect.com/images/products/' + thumbnails + '">');  
            }); 
    }
});
```

I am pretty sure the problem comes from `$( ".Thumbnails" ).remove();` but i need it to remove all the images with class `Thumbnails` and then replace them with the new ones which are appended with the same structure and class. When this code is executed the **CLICK** function on `Thumbnails` is just not responding. There are no output errors ot what so ever. Why my `click` function is not working anymore ?

I am pretty sure you can help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In javascript you must add event handle of class in loop but using jquery you don't need to loop. Jquery do this work by himself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when **generating elements dynamically**.

*General Syntax*

```
$(staticParentElement).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

*Example*

```
$('#ThumbnailHolder div').on('click', '.Thumbnails', function(){    
    var BigImageLink = $( this ).attr( "bigimagelink" );
    $('#ImgBigLink').attr('href', BigImageLink);
    $('#productImgDefault').attr('src', BigImageLink);
});
```